# ruby sinatra how to redirect with regex

Tags: ruby, regex, redirect, sinatra

I am trying to move stuff at root to /en/ directory to make my little service multi-lingual.

So, I want to redirect this url

mysite.com/?year=2018

to

mysite.com/en/?year=2018

My code is like

`get %r{^/(\?year\=\d{4})$} do |c|
  redirect "/en/#{c}"
end`

but it seems like I never get #{c} part from the url.

Why is that? or are there just better ways to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `request.path` variable to get the information you're looking for.

For example,

```
get "/something" do
  puts request.path # => "/something"
  redirect "/en#{request.path}"
end
```

However if you are using query parameters (i.e. `?yeah=2000`) you'll have to manually pass those off to the redirect route.

Kind of non-intuitively, there's a helper method for this in ActiveRecord.

```
require 'active_record'
get "/something" do
  puts params.to_param
  # if params[:year] is 2000, you'll get "year=2000"

  redirect "/en#{request.path}?#{params.to_param}"
end
```

You could alternatively write your own helper method pretty easily:

```
def hash_to_param_string(hash)
  hash.reduce("") do |string, (key, val)|
    string << "#{key}=#{val}&"
  end
end

puts hash_to_param_string({key1: "val1", key2: "val2"})
# => "key1=val1&key2=val2"
```

Comment: OK... so you can get parameter part in the url with params!
I could make it work!

Thanks max p.